# How can I guess if some letter in some word is silent or not?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letter

I was thinking about two particular words "Tsunami" and "gnarl". Both of them seems almost impossible to be pronounced by me (the *ts* and *gn* part). I guess this is because my tongue is not habituated with pronouncing such constructs. So I can keep "t" in "Tsunami" and "g" in "gnarl" pronouncing as "silent letters" in my utterance. Now the question arises how can I know if a letter in a word is silent or not? Is there any way to guess it if I have no dictionary in my hand at that moment?

Comment: Incidentally, some people do pronounce the "t" in "tsunami".  Some people don't pronounce it, but [believe that they do](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3027).

Comment: @snailplane: That second group would presumably be the same people who believe they pronounce a T in *prints*, but not in *prince*. You're right some people pronounce the initial T in *tsunami*, but in practice I don't think anyone does in *prints*.

Comment: "tsunami" should not be considered, because it is really a Japanese word; we just use it in English as its a commonly known word worldwide. When pronounced by a  native  Japanese speaker, you will hear a "t" sound in "tsu", though a native English speaker (maybe westerners in general) would have to listen for it, since the "t" is weak compared to the "s" sound.

Comment: @user3169 You can make that argument, but I would say: "tsunami" entered English [over a hundred years ago](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tsunami&searchmode=none), can be found in [many English language dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=tsunami&ls=a), has undergone [*regularization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28linguistics%29), and is known by virtually all native speakers, some of whom don't know the word is from Japanese.  Because of these traits, I feel it is best described as an *English word borrowed from Japanese*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the general case, it is impossible to know for certain the mapping between graphical units — letters — and sounds in the English language.  That is simply the way it is.

In the specific case, there is no English word that starts with /ts/ or /gn/, because that sequence cannot occur in that position in English.  Therefore the first letter of each of those two pairs is always silent.

There are enough of these specific cases that a given native speaker stands an excellent chance of guessing the same pronunciation as some other native speaker will guess.  And therefore this indeed a system to it all.

It just takes a very long time to learn if you are not born to it.

Comment: Unless it's GNU...

Comment: I disagree with the no word begins with /ts/ premise. I've heard tsunami (/tsu.nami/), tzar (/tsa:/) "tsk" (/ˈtɪsk/) and even tsetse (/ˈtsɛ.tsɛ/)

Comment: @Matt It's definitely true that exceptions exist for some speakers some of the time, but *not for most speakers*.  Similarly, in initial position /ks/ becomes /z/ (xenon, xylophone) and /ps/ becomes /s/ (psyche, psoriasis) *for most speakers*; these rules aren't absolute, and they can change over time, but at present exceptions aren't terribly common.

Comment: @Matt What in the world is a *tsa*?

Comment: @tchrist: "tsar" or "tzar", pronounced /tsa:/ http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsar, meaning historically the emperor of Russia or the Slavic kingdoms, figuratively meaning a person with great power, or informally in the context of politics someone who oversees a particular area of governance.

Comment: @Matt Um, that’s "tsar" not "tsa".

Comment: @tchrist: In which case I don't know what you're talking about. You were the first person to mention "tsa" as a word on this thread. If you re-read you'll find that I said /tsa:/ (i.e. the pronunciation of "tsar") was a counterexample of a word that begins with a /ts/ sound. I never claimed that there was a word spelt t-s-a.

Comment: *Tsar* has an *r* in it.  The silent letter occurs at the beginning, not at the end.

Comment: @tchrist: http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tsar?q=tsar: Pronunciation: /zɑː, tsɑː/

Comment: @Matt I keep forgetting that some people have trouble pronouncing their *r*'s. Yes, well, dialects aside, there is a phonemic *r* there, one spoken by most English speakers, even if you can’t quite get it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a list with words with silent letters from an old English textbook. I keep adding on them. While the classification is not exhaustive, it is giving you insight, because you can group as below. You also can do the same - make such a vocabulary list. I give few examples for each group.

--*silent b words*: lamb, climb, bomb
crumb, thumb, plumbing
debt, doubt

--*silent g words*: gnaw, diaphragm, phlegm
align, benign, sign

--*silent  gh words*: high, eight, neighbor
delight, fright, tight
bough, though, caught

--*silent h words*: ghost, honest, hour
rheumatism, rhyme, rhythm

--*silent k words*: knee, knife, knack
knob, know, knock

--*silent l words*: balk, stalk, walk
calf, half, could

--*silent n words*: column, autumn, solemn

--*silent p words*: pseudo, psychologist, receipt

--*silent w words*: who, wrap, wrestle
write, wrong, wry

--*other words with silent letters*: handsome (d), vegetable (e), business(i), aisle (s), listen(t)

Note: 1) In general if a base word has a silent letter, its conjugates keep the letter silent, and conversely. Example: stalk->stalking
But there are some exceptions: Example: black (ck not silent), blackguard (ck is silent)
2) some words can be pronounced in both ways. Example: tsetse, calm (with l silent or not)
3) some words are quite unusual: corps (ps is silent), colonel (l silent with rhotacization)

Comment: For me, the 'ck' in "blackguard" is not quite silent. It turns into [gemination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) on the 'g'. That is, the 'g' in "blackguard" is longer than that in "laggard".

Comment: Possible, another example is damn/damnation which I found from Wikipedia, which calls these "inert letters". Thanks

Comment: @Peter Shor unless you can bring evidence to that, otherwise it is anecdotical evidence for me. Neither [Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blackguard?q=blackguard) or [Thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blackguard)-though this has some weird non-IPA symbols, or Cambridge Dictionary of Pronunciation shows a long "g" (g:)